# CakePHP 2.4.4 How can I retrieve a User record excluding the password, except for Auth, in one place?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, passwords, find

This is the code I currently have:

```
public function afterFind($results = array(), $primary = false) {
    foreach($results as $key => &$value) {
        if(isset($results[$key][$this->alias]['password'])) {
            unset($results[$key][$this->alias]['password']);;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

This is great when retrieving user data in general, but Auth obviously needs the password. Is there a way to run the above only if it's not Auth doing the find? I don't want to use some sort of field white/blacklist each time I have to find() to avoid retrieving the password.

Comment: Please don't forget to mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could attempt to inspect the call stack to see if you're inside an `Auth` call, but that will be a big performance impact.

If you need to hide the password, the best way to do that is in the view. You could also have a helper that dumps user data and its careful not to dump the password. This way you can code this "suppression" only once.

And I think that the Cake debugger is smart enough not to dump a password field inside and array (but you should not rely on that in a production environment).

In view, dumping user data (not just only password) is not a good idea. Emails need to be protected as well. So I am very aware and careful of what and where I print out user information.